# not able to understand gluLookat

Tags: c, opengl

I am new to openGL and I am facing some problem with openGL's gluLookat function. I have setup my origin at top-left corner of the glut window. I am placing the camera at the origin and trying to view a solid cube which I am creating at the origin and translating it to the center of the screen.

```
int w = glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_WIDTH);
int h = glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_HEIGHT);
windowWidth = w * 2 / 3;
windowHeight = h * 2 / 3;

 glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, windowWidth, windowHeight, 0, -1, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); //Placing camera at the origin.

    glPushMatrix(); // Set current matrix on the stack
      glTranslatef (windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2, 0.0); // Translating it to the center of the screen
      glutSolidSphere(5, 20,20); // creating the solid cube of radius 5
    glPopMatrix(); // Pop the old matrix without the transformations.
  glFlush(); 

 I am not able to view the solid cube on the screen. What is wrong with this piece of code.
```

Comment: This looks like C, not C++. Don't add tags for different languages.

Comment: my bad !. Thanks for editing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of window dimensions in ortho and lookAt is misleading, especially to yourself. In ortho you seem to want to make a viewing volume the size of the window, that's alright. But then you want your camera to be in the origin and looking towards the center of the window, however it is not really looking towards the center of the window but rather **to a point that is at the same distance as half the dimensions of the window**. Which doesn't really make much sense, since as you resize your window the sphere will move farther away (expand the window) or closer (shrink the window) to the camera.

Let's assume that the window has dimensions 640 x 480. This means that the sphere will be centered at `( 320, 240, 0 )`, which is 400 units distance from your camera. So your far value needs to be a bit higher than that in order for you to see your object.

---

To answer the "what's wrong part", in `glOrtho` the 6th parameter (zfar) is too small so your sphere will be well outside of the viewing volume.

There is no problem with the `gluLookAt` call. Just, as I said, it's doing something different than you intended.

The real problem is not your code but in your understanding of your code and OpenGL functions. So I recommend that you search about viewing volume, orthogonal projection, perspective projection and view matrix.

Also, it wouldn't hurt you to learn modern OpenGL and drop the old OpenGL functionality entirely.